# Is it possible for a Java update to have removed a soft link to the system certs?

Tags: centos, java, update

I did a recent update to open jdk java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64.

Today we got a call from our customer that there was an error in the system. Upon further checking, we found that the following directory was empty:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-1.b16.el7_3.x86_64/jre/lib/security
```

Is it possible that the update removed the soft link:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   41 Jul 26 12:39 cacerts -> ../../../../../../../etc/pki/java/cacerts
```

Or did something else happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen something similar to this, with a Java update breaking the cert-behavior of an app. Was the application restarted after the java update?  RPM will install the new java and remove the old one, including the certs.

Always restart all java applications after updating Java.

The same applies to other libraries -- what is the point of updating openssl if all the running applications are still using the older/deleted version?

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, since my ass is on the line for this. But thank you for letting me know how to avoid it in the future. <3